# Unable to Build Docker Containers with Docker Compose: "Failed to Compute Cache Key: Failed to Calculate Checksum"

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm encountering an issue while trying to build Docker containers using Docker Compose. Whenever I run `docker-compose up -d --build`, I receive the following error message:

```
 => ERROR [db 2/3] COPY compose/dev/db/pg.conf /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf                                               0.0s 
------
 > [db 2/3] COPY compose/dev/db/pg.conf /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 3f15a420-c6ba-47ed-8967-08acfe264b2c::azvdjjhv07vtjx2zs9lswuxwu: "/compose/dev/db/pg.conf": not found
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.7"

x-variables: &variables
  ENV_STAGE: local

services:
  profiles:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/dev/web/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./web/:/usr/src/web/
      - postgres_socket:/postgres_socket
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      <<: *variables
    env_file:
      - compose/dev/env/.env
      - compose/dev/env/.db.env
      - compose/dev/env/.data.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/dev/db/Dockerfile
    hostname: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "6435:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - postgres_socket:/postgres_socket
    env_file:
      - compose/dev/env/.db.env


volumes:
  postgres_data:
  postgres_socket:
```

I have confirmed that the referenced file `pg.conf` exists in the specified location. I'm using Docker version 25.0.2 and Docker Compose version v2.24.3-desktop.1.

Any insights into why I'm encountering this error and how I can resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: On the host system, where exactly are the `docker-compose.yml` and `pg.conf` files located?  (Also consider [edit]ing the question to remove the `profiles` service commented-out lines that aren't relevant to the specific question.)

Comment: `docker-compose.yml` is in the root folder and the `pg.conf` is in the `compose/dev/db` folder. 

And OK, will edit it. :)

Comment: It seems everything is as it should be, I really can not understand why is this error. :)

Comment: Try adding `./` in front of the filename in the Dockerfile, so it becomes `COPY ./compose/dev/db/pg.conf /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf`

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working again:

```=> ERROR [db 2/3] COPY ./compose/dev/db/pg.conf /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf                                             0.0s
```